# Poor performance on "responsive tables" javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

Pages on my site typically have 10 tables with 15 columns and 30 rows each.

On a desktop this is great.  On mobile it is bad.

My data is such that I don't want any wrapping either, nor a "stacking" solution.  However, my columns have clear priority, which is a key to fixing this.

What I'd like to do, is have JS that decides which columns can be displayed, starting with the most important ones.  It then adds in progressively less-important columns until it has a good fit within the users device.

Sounds simple, in theory.

In practice I've been playing with dataTables.net's responsive add-on, and the time to render such a page on my i5 XPS13 laptop is 3.5 seconds.  Without the JS code it's well under half a second.

Do you think what I'm asking is possible, or is that level of DOM manipulation always going to take a few seconds?

**EDIT: jsFiddle showing example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/2caay477/

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var start = performance.now();
        $('table').DataTable( {
            paging:   false,
            ordering: false,
            info:     false,
            autoWidth: false,
            deferRender: false,
            orderClasses: false,
            jQueryUI: false,
            lengthChange: false,
            processing: false,
            scrollX: false,
            scrollY: false,
            searching: false,
            serverSide: false,
            stateSave: false,
            responsive: {
                details: {
                   // display: '',
                   // type: ''
                }
            }
        });

        alert(performance.now() - start);
    });
```

**averages 250ms on my machine, and that's for only one table of 33 rows.**

Comment: This question is too broad without a context. Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added that now @halfzebra, thanks!

Comment: If code snippet above represents your current DataTables settings, I would really like to know, why do you even use DataTables? The responsiveness is clearly a performance killer there, I would recommend to take [infinity.js](http://airbnb.io/infinity/) and put some CSS magic on top to hide columns using `@media` queries. PS: try removing `responsive` property, you'll see x5 performance boost.

Comment: The responsive part is the only thing I'm really interested in, and datatables was the first recommendation I found that could handle the column priorities.